# ActionBar overflow icon refuses to change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-styles

I have been trying to change the overflow icon (the three dots) in the actionbar to just be white instead of gray. I have followed everyone's recommendations but it stays the same. Here is my code:

```
<style name="ActionBar.AccentColor.Background" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverflow</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/accent_dark</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/accent_dark</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionButtonOverflow" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_action_back_white</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:contentDescription">"Lala"</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
     <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.AccentColor.Background</item>
</style>
```

I have even created a new app and that works 100%. One idea was that perhaps the apklib project I was including was causing the problem, so I moved everything out of the apklib and tested again. No idea what is happening!

Comment: You should provide the targeted version of your app. App compat is all about backward porting and you will probably have to create 2-3 different styles to apply your custom action bar theme to all versions of Android.

Answer (score 10):

You have misplaced `android:actionOverflowButtonStyle` item. It has to be defined in the theme, not inside `android:actionBarStyle`.

Change the styles to the following, it should work:

```xml
<style name="ActionBar.AccentColor.Background" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@color/accent_dark</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/accent_dark</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionButtonOverflow" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_action_back_white</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:contentDescription">"Lala"</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
     <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.AccentColor.Background</item>
     <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverflow</item>
</style>
```